How can I fix "This mint account has an edition but none was provided" error?
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { 
  fetchMetadataFromSeeds, 
  updateV1,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { keypairIdentity, publicKey, createSignerFromKeypair } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';
import fs from 'fs';

const umi = createUmi('<RPC_URL>');

// NFT mint address
const mint = publicKey('<PUBLIC_KEY>');

const wallet = './my_wallet.json';
const secretKey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(wallet, 'utf-8')).secretKey;
const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secretKey));

const newAuthority = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, keypair);

async function updateNFT() {
  try {
    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint })

    await updateV1(umi, {
      mint,
      authority: newAuthority,
      data: { ...initialMetadata, name: 'Updated Asset' },
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating NFT:', error);
  }
}

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));
updateNFT();

I am trying to update the updateAuthority of an NFT I have authority over but I keep getting an error:
  transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x6c',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: IX: Update',
    'Program log: Auth type: Metadata',
    'Program log: This mint account has an edition but none was provided.',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 25554 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x6c'
  ]


I think your nft might have an edition instance and you'll need to pass in this account to the update instruction
async function updateTMDAsset() {
    const mint = publicKey(" "); // your mint address 
    const edition = findMasterEditionPda(umi, { mint });

    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });

    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...initialMetadata, name: "Updated Asset" },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        edition,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
